# Using javascript and ajax to fill an input field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following javascript which is intended to be used to dynamically fill another input field with the data retrieved via ajax. If I set it to fill a div it works, but changing to an input, it stops working.
My javascript is:

```
function showCD(str)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById('txtHint').value=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","script.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Html is:

```
<input type="text" name="cds" value="" onKeyUp="showCD(this.value)">

<input type="text" name="txtHint" id="txtHint" />
```

As I say, if i replace the latter input with a div with the id of "txtHint" and alter the javascript to:

```
document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

it works.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the response look like? Can you parse it into a JSON object and then assign the value? (e.g. `var res = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); document.getElementById('txtHint').value = res.var;`)

Comment: "it stops working" - what happens?

Comment: The response is just a number. It's a php script that converts a postcode into a longitude/latitude. If i make the script just output a number, it still fails and only displays when I make the div the target rather than the input field.

Comment: I also tried your JSON suggestion to no avail :(

Comment: What _exactly_ is the response from the server? You can do a `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` to find out.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far :)

When I do it using your JSON, I get invalid characted. Using the method I had originally I don't see anything logged when attempting to type something into the first box. Thanks.

Comment: "it still fails" - what happens?

Comment: @Igor

It doesn't fill in the text box. Nothing appears.

Comment: 1. type somethign in `txtHint` input, 2. add `alert(document.getElementById('txtHint').value);` to your code before you assign the `value`, what does it show?

Comment: Where in the code should I add this? Sorry, new to Javascript.

Comment: @user2069576 replace `document.getElementById('txtHint').value=xmlhttp.responseText;` with `alert("Server Value: " + xmlhttp.responseText)`. What does the alert say when you type?

Comment: OK, putting that in, using chrome, it says "the page at xxxx says: " and that's it. Nothing else.

Comment: OK, put your code back in place. Directly _above_ `document.getElementById('txtHint').value=xmlhttp.responseText;` that line place the following code: `alert("Value sent to server: " + str + ". Text reply from server: " + xmlhttp.responseText);`

Comment: @Lance

It says Server Value: then a long/latitude. For example, this exact result was:

    Server Value: 52.9881750-1.1224498

Comment: is `id` `"txtHint"` unique on the page?